# SQL Update Trigger Error-(Cannot create trigger because table has foreign key with a update cascade)

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am using `SQL` server 2008 and I have `payment` table and `paymentLog` table.

```
Create Table Tab_Payment
(
    Eid integer NOT NULL, 
    Date_of_Reflect date NOT NULL, 
    Amount integer NOT NULL,
    ...
    Constraint PK_Payment Primary Key(Eid,Date_of_Reflect),
    Constraint FK_Emp Foreign key (Eid) references Tab_Employee(Eid) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

I am going to used a trigger to insert data to paymentLog.

```
Create Trigger Trigger_Payment_Audit
on Tab_Payment
after  update
As
    ...
GO
```

I cannot create the trigger. Below error comes. What should I do to fix this.
**Cannot create INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger 'Trigger_Payment_Audit' on 'Tab_Payment'. This is because table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading UPDATE.**

I have found similar post on SO. Bout that did't helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Finally I fixed my Problem. Actually there is not a real error on there. That is only a error which indicated by the editor. Even it is indicated like there is an error, I was able to run the trigger.